# Is there attached property in C# itself?

Tags: c#, wpf

In C# itself, is there something like "attached property" used in WPF?

Comment: What do you mean "In C# itself"?  C# is a language specification, how could it possibly have "attached properties"?  The question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @EdS How could a language specification possibly have "attached properties"? By including them in the specification, no? How does the question make no sense? Seems pretty clear to me. The fact that the answer is no, doesn't make it nonsensical or "not a real question".

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: Fair enough.  I suppose the language spec *could* call then out if they were implemented at that level (like a property is).

Comment: I assume you mean something like extension methods but for properties? Unfortunately not at the present time.

Comment: This question should not have been closed as "not a real question". We considered adding something like WPF style "attached properties" to C# 4.0 and so it is a perfectly sensible question to ask whether the language supports it or not. The question is not ambiguous, vague, incomplete, broad, or rhetorical and can reasonably be answered (with "no") in its current form.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The short answer is no. The slightly longer answer is that this is a bit of an unfortunate story. We designed "extension properties" for C# 4 and got as far as implementing (but not testing) them when we realized, oh, wait, the thing we designed is not really compatible with WPF-style properties. Rather than redesign and reimplement the feature we ended up cutting it.

The even longer version is here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/05/why-no-extension-properties.aspx

Answer (score 2):

AttachedProperties are part of the .NET Framework, not part of the C# language specification, and specifically part of the System.Activities.Presentation.Model namespace, which is WPF specific.

Comment: I'd bet the question is referring to `DependencyProperty` and `DependencyObject` in `System.Windows`, not `System.Activities.Presentation.Model` (which looks like WF stuff)

Answer (score 2):

In WPF, an attached property allows you to do something like:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="I know nothing about grids!" />
```

This would be like having a class in C# defined as:

```
public class TextBlock
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And being able to do this:

```
var tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Grid.Row = 2; // this line would not compile
```

In order to make this work, you'd need to pass a `Grid` object into your TextBlock class:

```
public class TextBlock
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Grid Grid { get; set; }

    public TextBlock(Grid grid)
    {
        Grid = grid;
    }
}
```

But I don't think there's anything directly equivalent to the way attached properties work in WPF. You'd need to build it by hand.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx) class to attach arbitrary state to an instance. You can combine it with extension methods to create a form of [extension properties](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2011/03/c-mixins-with-state.html), but unfortunately without using the nice property syntax in C#.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're thinking of getters and setters.

They are created like this:

```
public class Person
{
    //default constructor 
    public Person()
        {
        }

    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        //set the person name
        set { this._Name = value; }
        //get the person name 
        get { return this._Name; }
    }
}
```

More on how they work here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786(v=vs.71).aspx